# Background-reacting navigation for one page websites - working script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good morning!

I want to share with you a simple script I made for the purposes of my company new website. It allows you to make a floating navigation bar which smoothly changes its background.

For now it's working with jQuery. My question is - is it possible to made this in pure CSS? My previous idea was to make navigation container with overflow: hidden and position: absolute + menu with position: fixed. Everything worked well until I realized that Firefox can't handle with this combination.

I'm waiting for yours ideas :)

Here's the code and preview:

```js
var nav = $('.nav'),
    navHeight = nav.height();

// Duplicate navigation
var navReversed = nav
    .clone(true)
    .addClass('nav-reversed')
    .insertAfter(nav);

var navs = $('.nav'),
    slides = $('.slide');

/* ... */

// onScroll event
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
        slide;

    // Find first visible slide
    slides.each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().top > scrollTop)
            return false;

        slide = $(this);
    });

    if (slide.length) {
        var id = '#' + slide.attr('id'),
            slideNext = slide.next('.slide');

        var clipTop = clipBottom = 'auto';

        if (slide.hasClass('slide-reversed')) {
            clipBottom = Math.max(slideNext.offset().top - scrollTop, 0);
        }
        else {
            clipTop = navHeight;

            if (slideNext.length && slideNext.hasClass('slide-reversed')) {
                clipTop = Math.min(slideNext.offset().top - scrollTop, clipTop);
            }
        }

        if (clipTop !== 'auto') {
            clipTop = Math.round(clipTop) + 'px';
        }

        if (clipBottom !== 'auto') {
            clipBottom = Math.round(clipBottom) + 'px';
        }

        navReversed.css('clip', 'rect('+clipTop+',auto,'+clipBottom+',auto)');

        /* ... */
    }
}).trigger('scroll');
```

Full version: http://jsfiddle.net/greenek/NL7Fh/

[image: Preview]

Comment: What do you mean by *Firefox can't handle with this combination*? Can you show us the CSS you tried?

Comment: Webkit in this case hide box with position: fixed when its outside the container. Firefox don't. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/greenek/qB6bb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try checkbox hack http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/, there are :target too but you can't higlight the link. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lqvpA